# how do i install tensorflow-node on Windows 10?

Tags: tensorflow

I have been running into problems with installing `tensorflow-node` on my Windows 10 desktop. What are the exact steps to install it?

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure you have `package.json` file in your directory that at least looks like this:

   `{ "private": true }`
2. make sure you have `windows-build-tools` installed globally:

   `npm install -g --production windows-build-tools`

   this should give you:

   `> + windows-build-tools@5.1.0`
3. make sure you have `node-gyp` installed globally:

   `npm install -g node-gyp`
4. install `tensortflow-node` locally:

   `npm install tensort-flow --save-dev`
5. optionally (recommended) install gpu support for tensorflow

   `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu --save-dev`

also check with the official installation instructions at: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-node

also you might find helpful:

- https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1463#issuecomment-396431904
- https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/702#issuecomment-280230515