# how can we use Tensorflowjs in Nodejs or Reactjs or core JavaScript for detecting single car object from an image?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, tensorflow

I have been trying to use tensorflowjs node library like @tensorflow/tfjs-node , but i couldn't install this npm in my windows system back-end in nodejs. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: May be it will be helpful to others if you would please share what steps were undertaken, what errors were encountered, and what remediation (if any) was attempted & any result/consequence thereof.

Comment: Also, FWIW, you may verify if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55426074/13658816) provides any relevant info.

Comment: Thanks for providing solution @jsN00b , I ll try it as said. But as per my understanding i have installed node-pre-gyp globally also still i am getting its error and because of this i am unable to install @tensorflow/tfjs-node .